# Where can I add assets in symfony 5?

Tags: symfony, assets

I'm using symfony 5 and I have no idea where can I pu my css, js, images files.

I read many posts about it but none helped me...

I tried:

- composer require symfony/asset
- symfony console assets:install

Here is the way i am using asset function in my twig files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/base.css') }}">
```

And yes I have a file at public/css/base.css...
But when I inspect the result page, my line is replaced by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/base.css">
```

Did someone have any idea ?

Best regards,

Comment: If such folders do not exist, what keeps you from creating them?

Comment: Hi, you mean i need to create these 5 folders ? and then what ? where should i put my css files ? all of them ? My question is about the best practice. I supposed that symfony creators put a directory for that inside the framework. So if these directories don't exist, so they are not the good place for my assets files.

Anyway, -2 on this question, can anybody tell me what is the problem with it ??

Comment: Create the folders you need, and place the files you need there. There is no reason to have all these folders if you don't need them - especially as `src/AppBundle` is not connected to assets after all, and should not been used since Symfony 4 (which abandoned the AppBundle construct)

Comment: @Nico it seems you don't understand that the question's author doesn't know at all how the assets system works in Symfony. That's why I tried to explain it in my answer.

Comment: No. Typically the answer of Florian is good because he told me that the right folder is public/ and then i should create folder inside it for css, js, ... but the 6 folders I am talking in the question are bad because it's not the good way to do it. If everybody create folder for no reason, another dev can't continue a project from other one because it will be unreadible. More, i'm not using a framework to recreate everithing. I'm using it in order to use  what it give me, and here, it gave me the public/ repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're NOT using webpack (or webpack encore), your assets should be in your public folder which is the root of your public project. For example, if you have a file called style.css in public/css/style.css, you can access it in your browser with the url (assuming you use a local server started in the public dir) http://localhost:8000/css/style.css.

The Symfony asset component goal is to guess if your project is in a subdirectory and therefore to resolve the correct path. In order to use it in a Twig template with the previous imaginary file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

The asset function will be able to produce the right path for your file.

If you're using webpack, the setup is a bit harder so if you don't I won't explain it here.

Comment: Moreover, the resources you mentioned seems outdated (mostly related to Symfony 2 and 3) and the command assets:install is responsible of installing bundle's assets.