# symfony 5 - Path to the assets from subdirectories

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assets, symfony5

I've got a problem with the path of assets on Symfony 5.
This is a structure of assets in the project:

```
app/
    public/
        css/
            style.css 
            ...
            ...
```

Everythings works fine when I do not have subdirectories in URL, but when URL looks like:

```
https://example.com/catalog/course
```

Symfony looking for file:

`https://example.com/catalog/course/style/style.css`

The properly address is:

`https://example.com/css/style.css`

That works like we can read in documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#linking-to-css-javascript-and-image-assets

Regardless of the subdirectories in URl, I have only one style.css. How can I determine to looking for the properly path of assets?

Comment: Are you using webpack ? or is that a raw symfony project ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I add assets in symfony 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675401/where-can-i-add-assets-in-symfony-5)

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony, you can use the asset() function to generate the correct URL for an asset, regardless of the subdirectories in the URL.
This function takes the path to the asset, relative to the public directory, as its argument. For example, to link to the style.css file in the example you provided, you would use the following code in your Twig template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```